# Increment column by one if date column is changing

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I need help in writing a SQL query to increment column only if the date of column (DATE) is changing on insert statement:

Initial table structure :

```
ID            DATE          NAME
--            ----          ----
1             20170428      abc
```

Now next day, I have to insert three different records. For that table should look like:

```
ID            DATE          NAME
--            ----          ----
1             20170428      abc
2             20170429      def
2             20170429      ghi
2             20170429      jkl
```

This above data I'm reading from a `.csv` file and date is returned as current system date.

So `ID` should be incremented only if date is changed from its last record in a table.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: HOw are you making your insert (post code)?

Comment: using pl sql procedure which is getting called by an bash script.Should i post code also @etsa ??

Comment: A column called ID having multiple records with the same value is very confusing.

Comment: column ID is just an example can be anything

Comment: yes, your pl/sql is useful to help you.  Moreover, you should point out some of the requisites: 1) loading date is ALWAYS date of the day (the file hasn't or it's fixed for any loading).  2) you are going to check ONLY the last date loaded (es. MAX(date) present in table) and compare it with sysdate.  In this case it should be quite easy to get ID for that max date and add +1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to setup an auto increment column which behaves this way.  However, one alternative, which might even be preferable in many ways, would be to just generate your `ID` column on demand using Oracle's `DENSE_RANK()`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) ID,
    DATE,
    NAME
FROM yourTable
```